# Why it's print grabage value?

Tags: c

In this code I want to print floating point value of 9/5 which is 1.8 than why it print the garbage value. why I try to print the int value than it print 1 which is correct but why it print grabage rather than printing 1.8?

#include <stdio.h>

```
int main() {
      printf("%f", 9/5);
      //printf("%d", 9/5);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use `-Werror`, it will help you understand the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of a variadic argument (argument in the `...` part of the function declaration) passed to a function depends only on what you pass to the function (in your case `9/5`), not on the string argument. `9` and `5` are of type `int`, so their quotient is the fractional quotient converted to `int` by truncation towards zero, which is `1`. Then, by integer promotions, `int` is converted to `int` (if you passed `(short) (9/5)`, then by integer promotions, this would also have been converted to `int`).

Comment: got it! and if I do type casting would it also worked?

Comment: What do you mean? If you pass `(double) (9/5)`, then the `double` `1.0` would be passed.